BOLT12: what is the invreq_metadata field for?
BOLT12 has a invreq_metadata field. What is this for and what are some examples of what the data in the field could look like in practice? Is this a way for a node to distinguish two different invoice_requests that it may have open for the same offer (or two different open invoice_requests that it may have open for a merchant-pays-user flow)? Or, is there some other field that is used to distinguish open invoice_requests when all other fields are the same?
